# How to prevent redirect to request again if using the same route in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I am using node, express, MongoDB, and handlebars, for rendering a page.

The problem is that when get-request gets to the server, it renders the page and then requests a second time. How double-request can be avoided.

The page has no scripts for reloading. all the fetchs are event driven (like on click etc.)

this is the code:

```js
const client = new MongoClient(url, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
});


router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  console.log('--------------------')
  console.log(req.originalUrl)
  client.connect(err => {
  
    console.log("Connected successfully to database");

    const db = client.db(dbName);
    const students = db.collection("students");

    students
      .find()
      .sort({ insertTime: -1 })
      .toArray((err, result) => {
     
        console.log("Found records");
      
        res.render("students", { students: result });
        return client.close();
      })
          
  }); 

});
```

This is the Page (rendered by handlebars):

```html
<form method="POST" action="/addStudent">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First name" name='name'>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name" name='last'">
    </div>
    <div class=" col">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="add studnet">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<div class='average'>
  <button class='btn btn-primary' onclick='getAverage(event)'>Get Average</button>
</div>
<ul class="list-group">
  {{#each students}}
  <li class="list-group-item"><button class="btn btn-danger" id={{this._id}}
      onclick='deleteStudent(event)'>Delete</button> {{this.name}} {{this.last}} has average of <input type='number'
      max=100 min=0 value={{this.average}} onchange='updateAverage(event, "{{this._id}}")' /> </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

These are the functions:

```js
function addStudent(e) {
  console.log('addStudent')
  e.preventDefault();

  const formObj = e.target.elements;
  const student = {
    name: formObj.name.value,
    last: formObj.last.value
  };
  console.log(student);

  if (student.name && student.last) {
    fetch("/addStudent", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(student),
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    })
      .then(res => {
        console.dir(res);
        res.json().then(resJson => {
          console.dir(resJson);
        });
      })

      .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  } else {
    alert("Name an family is requierd");
  }
}

function deleteStudent(e) {
  console.log('deleteStudent')
  let studentObj = { studentId: e.target.id };
  fetch("/deleteStudent", {
    method: "DELETE",
    body: JSON.stringify(studentObj),
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  }).then(res => {
    console.dir(res);
    location.reload();
  });
}

function updateAverage(e, studentId) {
  console.log('updateAverage')
  const grade = { grade: e.target.valueAsNumber, studentId };

  fetch("/updateAverage", {
    method: "PUT",
    body: JSON.stringify(grade),
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  }).then(res => {
    console.dir(res);
  });
}

function getAverage(e) {
  console.log('getAverage')
  fetch("/getAverage", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({}),
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  })
    .then(res => {
      console.dir(res);
      res.json().then(resJson => {
        console.dir(resJson);
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: what do the scripts for the page look like that is sending the double requests?

Comment: The page has no scripts for reloading. all the fetchs are event driven (like on click etc.)

Comment: If you're experiencing multiple requests from your client then I believe this will likely be a client side bug. I would post the some code for the client side as well (for example you may accidentally be calling your function attached to your onClick right way instead of adding it as a callback)

Comment: @Willman.Codes, thanks. I added the html for the page and the functions

Comment: maybe try (in on your server side logic) to remove the `return` and put `client.close();` outside the `.toArray`

Comment: removed the 'return': no change. moved the 'close' outside the client, and the client  is waiting for a reponce...

Comment: `client.close();` should still be within the `client` closure i just meant to move it outside of the `.toArray()` closures. however i don't think this is your underlying issue was just a suggestion

Comment: @TalYaron Yes you are right Tal, my answer is wrong and have deleted. My mistake. I didn't see that top line function. Your code looks normal to me. I think you have code somewhere that is making your page render again. Check your other router files or index server file, see if its working properly. One of my projects, I had this same problem. I couldn't find the solution. I had to revert back to older code and redo the page and it worked...so its somewhere.

Comment: All is good :-)